# Dynamically set object property value

Tags: java, object, properties

I'm new to Java and am trying to figure out how to dynamically set a property's value for a custom object.  I'm using an XML parser which loops through the elements in an XML file and I'm just trying to set the strings to my temporary value.

```
public MyObject tempObj; //gets instantiated before child elements
public String tempValue; //gets set before each loop

public void stepThroughChildElement(string elementName) {
    switch (elementName) {
        case "Id":
            tempObj.Id = Integer.parseInt(tempValue);
            break;
        case "Version":
            tempObj.Version = Float.parseFloat(tempValue);
            break;
        default:
            //something like this   
            //tempObj.setProperty(elementName, tempValue);
            //or
            //tempObj[elementName] = tempValue;
            break;
    }

}
```

In JavaScript, I'd just use the second example `Object["property"] = value;`, but obviously Java doesn't work like that.  I also found this [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) object, but I can't tell if it is relevant.

Comment: Either use a `Map` as [others](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18828848/2071828) have suggested. For a more flexible approach use an XML binding framework such as JAXB.

Comment: Don't try to use Java like another loosely typed language.

Comment: I'm using SAX http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Java is statically typed, you can't just add a property like that. You would have to give your object a Map<String, String> the other properties.

If the object already has the properties defined, you could hard-code each one or use java.reflection to do it more dynamically. Use code assist and look at all of the methods available to you after you call tempObj.getClass().  You might be able to access the fields directly or you might have to look up and call the setter methods.

Comment: I was just looking for a shortcut, rather than to say `myObject.String1 = tempValue;`, `myObject.String2 = tempValue;` etc..

Comment: Reflection will be your friend, then. I would recommend caching the method names that you'll be calling as you find them.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)?

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put(key, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
tempObj.put("key", new Object());  // use HashtMap's put method
tempObj.setProperty("key", "value"); // use Proerties' setProperty method
```

Comment: Use a `HashMap` rather than a `HashTable`. `HashTable` is a deprecated collection type.

Comment: This means my `MyObject` needs to extend a `HashMap`?